# How to import an api library to eclipse? JAVA

Tags: java, api

first of all, thanks for all the times this comunity helped me, and sorry for my english.

The problem: I want to use a public library for the RIOT games api, this library:

https://github.com/aaryn101/lol4j

When i tried to add the library eclipse don't recognize the classes!

I dont't know how to add it!, i searched, really, but i can't find it, thanks!

pd: I'm using Eclipse!

Here is an example from the library:

```
Lol4JClient client = new Lol4JClientImpl("apiKey");

ChampionListDto championList = client.getAllChampions(Region.NA, true);
RecentGamesDto recentGames = client.getRecentGames(Region.NA, 19163557);
Map<String, LeagueDto> leaguesData = client.getLeaguesData(Region.NA, 19163557);
PlayerStatsSummaryListDto playerStatsSummaries = client.getPlayerStatsSummaries(Region.NA, 19163557, Season.SEASON_3);
RankedStatsDto rankedStats = client.getRankedStats(Region.NA, 19163557, Season.SEASON_3);
MasteryPagesDto masteryPages = client.getMasteryPages(Region.NA, 19163557);
```

Comment: Did you download the built library (a .jar file) or something else?

Comment: I downloaded the zip of the project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library hosted on github contains a gradle build script that you can use to build a jar file. If you don't already have gradle download it from http://www.gradle.org/installation and configure it.

Extract the ZIP

Rename junit.properties.sample to junit.properties and enter values for variable defined within the file.

Assuming you have access to a terminal or the command line, run the following command from the lol4j-master folder: gradle jar

You should have something like the image below. Then you can import the jar file the normal way into your project.

[image]

PS: This method will save you the headache of downloading the necessary libraries.

Running the command: gradle jar:

```
tshenolo$ gradle jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.0/jackson-databind-2.3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/oss-parent/11/oss-parent-11.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.0/jackson-core-2.3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-client/2.4.1/jersey-client-2.4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/project/2.4.1/project-2.4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/jvnet-parent/4/jvnet-parent-4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2-bom/2.2.0-b21/hk2-bom-2.2.0-b21.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-common/2.4.1/jersey-common-2.4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.pom
...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 0):

When you download a ZIP you are probably downloading the full project sources, project, etc.

You need to either extract that to your hard drive and then load the project in an appropriate IDE and build it or look and see whether the project you are downloading offers a JAR download.

Either way what you need is a .JAR file either downloaded or produced by building the project. That JAR file can then be imported as a library.

Answer (score 0):

In Github, you can download the master copy (Download Zip).

Steps to add to eclipse:
This will include the classes in your project

1. extract it
2. copy the folder "lol4j" under lol4j-master/src/main/java to your project folder's src/
3. refresh the project
4. In the **same** project, in your classes, you can already use the api provided.
5. import the necessary classes when you see error **(by Ctrl+Shift+O or right click the red cross)**
6. some dependency jars are needed:

   e.g. com.fasterxml.jackson.*

you may need to import those dependency jars (by download from google) to the project as well by **right click the project ->
edit Java build path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs -> browse and add**

*P.S. I have tried myself in Eclipse, and it works*